# Laravel insert dynamic input values with radio button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am a beginner at Laravel, I want to insert a more dynamic address field to the database and I want to select one primary address using the radio button. I can able to add more address fields, but, I am unable to select one primary address because it's selecting all radio button values. I have given below using my code

**This is My Blade File**

```
    <div>
          <form action="{{ route('register.post') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" >
               @csrf
              <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-left">Address</label>
                   <div>
                     <table id="dynamicAddRemove">
                       <tr>
                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">Add More Details</button></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                              
                          </td>
                          <tr>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                  </div>    
                  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Save
                     </button>
                 </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var i = 0;
                    $("#add-btn").click(function(){
                        //alert("I am an alert box!");
                    ++i;
                    $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="moreFields['+i+'][house_no]" placeholder="House No" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="moreFields['+i+'][street_name]" placeholder="Street Name" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="moreFields['+i+'][area]" placeholder="Area" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="moreFields['+i+'][pincode]" placeholder="Pincode" class="form-control" /></td><td style="padding-left:50px;"><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="moreFields['+i+'][primary_address]" value="'+i+'"></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
                    });
                    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    });  
                    </script>
```

**This is My Controller File**

```
 public function postRegistration(Request $request)
{  
    $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    foreach ($request->moreFields as $key => $value) {
      
        Address::create([
            'user_id'=>$id,
            'house_no'=>$value['house_no'],
            'street_name'=>$value['street_name'],
            'area'=>$value['area'],
            'pincode'=>$value['pincode'],
            'primary_address'=>$value['primary_address'],
            
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try googling some solutions? there must be some tutorials from google to achieve this.

Comment: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/add-remove-multiple-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery-laravel-58example.html  like this

Comment: Yes I have tried some code and I can able to add more address fields but, I am unable to select one primary address because it's selecting all radio button values

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to make different name radio buttons use same name for all radio buttons so that user can not select other radio button after selecting one

```
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="moreFields" value="'+i+'">
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I have used your code but, I am getting Illegal string offset 'house_no' error

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong way as in controller you are using moreFields array using key value pair so i believe radio button here will not work.

Comment: '<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="primary_address" value="'+i+'"></td>'

Comment: Now am getting valid value, but it's not an array and getting a single value only so I don't know how to insert this value

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 8 Dynamic Radio Button Edit Page**
**This worked for me**

```
@foreach($lease_stores as $lease_store)
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="lease_store_id" id="inlineRadio1" @if($general_details->lease_store_id==$lease_store->id) checked value="{{$lease_store->id}}" 
                @else value="{{$lease_store->id}}"
                @endif>
               <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">{{$lease_store->name}} </label>              
              </div>
              @endforeach
```

**Controller master fetch**
$lease_stores=Leasestore::all();